# Adding a newly drawn feature in the published layer in the WFS-T function?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

This time, I would like to use the wfs-t function of OpenLayer for the first time, and update and add function to the layer issued to geoserver.
The update functionality is fully operational through this feature.
However, it has not been added for some reason in the add function.

It's my code

This is the gml option

```
 gmlJson[layerName]['insert'] = new ol.format.GML({
        featureNS : 'http://www.openplans.org/datas',
        featureType :layerName,
        srsName : 'EPSG:3857',
    })
```

Event to move drawn feature to wfs-t function

```
draw.on('drawend',(evt) => {
            transactWFS('insert',layerName, evt.feature)
})
```

A function that requests my geoserver through the wfs-t function

```
  function transactWFS(mode, layerName, f) {
    const find_feature = `feature:${layerName}`;
    const re_feature = new RegExp(find_feature, "g");
    //Change feature geometry column
    const find_geometry = `<Property><Name>geometry</Name>`;
    const re_geometry = new RegExp(find_geometry, "g");
        let node;
        switch (mode) {
            case 'insert':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(f, null, null, gmlJson[layerName]['insert']);
            // const insertElement = Array.from(node.childNodes.values())[0];
            // insertElement.setAttribute('idgen','UseExisting');
            break;
        case 'update':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, f, null, gmlJson[layerName]['upddel']);
            break;
            case 'delete':
                node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, f, gmlJson[layerName]['upddel']);
                break;
         }
        var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
        switch (mode) {
        case 'update':
            var payload = payload.replace("feature:"+layerName,"datas:"+layerName)
            .replace(re_feature, `datas:${layerName}`)
            .replace(re_geometry, `<Property><Name>the_geom</Name>`);
            break;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/datas/ows',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'xml',
            processData : false,
            contentType : 'text/xml',
            data : payload,
            error : (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }).done(function(data1,data2,data3) {
            console.log(data1);
            console.log(data2);
            console.log(data3)
            //mapJson[target_map].clear();
        }).always(function(){
            switch (mode) {
            case 'insert':
                var propNodes = node.getElementsByTagName("Property");
                console.log(propNodes)
                for (var i = 0; i < propNodes.length; i++) {
                    var propNode = propNodes[i];
                    var propNameNode = propNode.firstElementChild;
                    var propNameNodeValue = propNameNode.firstChild;
                    if (propNameNodeValue.nodeValue === "geometry") {
                        propNode.parentNode.removeChild(propNode);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        });
        // }).always(function(){
        //  switch (mode) {
        //  case 'insert':
        //      var propNodes = node.getElementsByTagName("Property");
        //      for (var i = 0; i < propNodes.length; i++) {
        //          var propNode = propNodes[i];
        //          var propNameNode = propNode.firstElementChild;
        //          var propNameNodeValue = propNameNode.firstChild;
        //          if (propNameNodeValue.nodeValue === "geometry") {
        //              propNode.parentNode.removeChild(propNode);
        //              break;
        //          }
        //      }
        //      break;
        //  }
        // });
    };
```

Result

[image]

Log shown on the geo server

```
Request: transaction
service = WFS
version = 1.1.0
baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
group[0] = wfs:insert=net.opengis.wfs.impl.InsertElementTypeImpl@27bc8c58 (feature: [SimpleFeatureImpl:projection=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: Layer<Layer id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: SubClasses<SubClasses id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: EntityHand<EntityHand id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null]], handle: null, idgen: <unset>, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
insert[0]:
    feature[0] = SimpleFeatureImpl:projection=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: Layer<Layer id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: SubClasses<SubClasses id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: EntityHand<EntityHand id=fid-433c1eaf_184a721e81a_-7f51>=null]
    idgen = GenerateNew
    inputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
releaseAction = ALL
```

--Part of xml

```
<Transaction
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 service="WFS"
 version="1.1.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs 
 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"
 >
 <Insert>
   <projection xmlns="datas">
    <geometry>
      <MultiLineString xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
        srsName="EPSG:3857">
        <lineStringMember>
         <LineString srsName="EPSG:3857">
          <posList srsDimension="2">
            14095337.931007672 4493662.703118336 14095348.73941191
            4493669.508409892
          </posList>
        </LineString>
      </lineStringMember>
    </MultiLineString>
  </geometry>
</projection>
```

;

In the insert part of the result, one was added, but the geoserver layer does not show any added appearance

For your information, the data store option for the issued layer is a shp file and is not using postgres.

Wouldn't it be applied for some reason?

Comment: what does the log file show? also we need to see the XML being sent to the server. please [edit] your question with the extra details

Comment: I understand. All I want to know is whether to use postgis to use wfs-t

Comment: Editing will work better with a database designed for multiple users editing at the same time.