# Drawing polygon elements inside layer of line type

Tags: geoserver, polygon, wfs-t

I solved the method of drawing on a map using wfs-t on the vector layer I published and storing it in that layer.
I'm asking you a question because there's a problem while testing various things

It is a problem that cannot be saved when the polygon is drawn inside the line type layer and added.

How do I add polygons to the line type layer?

my layer
[image]

[image]

The code is on the [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446122/adding-a-newly-drawn-feature-in-the-published-layer-in-the-wfs-t-function)

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the geometry type of the layer if it is `linestring` (or `multilinestring`) then no, if it is `geometry` then yes. That's not to say that this would be a good idea though, see this [section of the manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/mixed-geometries.html) for more discussion.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!